# Passing R Function as Parameter to RCpp Function

Tags: c++, r, function, rcpp

I'm trying to run something like

R

```
my_r_function <- function(input_a) {return(input_a**3)}
RunFunction(c(1,2,3), my_r_function)
```

CPP

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector RunFunction(NumericVector a, Function func)
{
  NumericVector b = NumericVector(a.size());
  for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    b[i] = func(a[i]);
  return b;
}
```

How would I make "Function func" actually work in Rcpp?

P.S. I understand there are ways to do this without Rcpp (apply comes to mind for this example) but I'm just using this as an example to demonstrate what I'm looking for.

Comment: [Like this?](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/r-function-from-c++/)

Comment: Extra point for linking to Rcpp Gallery article.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use the example in the link I provided above to get your code working; but you should also take note of Dirk's warning,

> Calling a function is simple and tempting. It is also slow as there
>   are overheads involved. And calling it *repeatedly* from inside your C++
>   code, possibly buried within several loops, is outright silly.

which can be demonstrated by modifying your above code slightly and benchmarking the two versions:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector RunFunction(Rcpp::NumericVector a, Rcpp::Function func)
{
  Rcpp::NumericVector b = func(a);
  return b;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector RunFunction2(Rcpp::NumericVector a, Rcpp::Function func)
{
  Rcpp::NumericVector b(a.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
    b[i] = Rcpp::as<double>(func(a[i]));
  }
  return b;
}

/*** R
my_r_function <- function(input_a) {return(input_a**3)}
x <- 1:10
##
RunFunction(x,my_r_function)

RunFunction2(x,my_r_function)
##
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  RunFunction(rep(1:10,10),my_r_function),
  RunFunction2(rep(1:10,10),my_r_function))

Unit: microseconds
                                       expr     min       lq       mean   median       uq      max neval
  RunFunction(rep(1:10, 10), my_r_function)  21.390  22.9985   25.74988  24.0840   26.464   43.722   100
 RunFunction2(rep(1:10, 10), my_r_function) 843.864 903.0025 1048.13175 951.2405 1057.899 2387.550   100

*/
```

Notice that `RunFunction` is ~40x faster than `RunFunction2`: in the former we only incur the overhead of calling `func` from inside the C++ code once, whereas in the latter case we have to make the exchange for each element of the input vector. If you tried running this on even longer vectors, I'm sure you would see a substantially worse performance from `RunFunction2` relative to `RunFunction`. So, if you are going to be calling R functions from inside of your C++ code, you should try to take advantage of R's native vectorization (if possible) rather than repeatedly making calls to the R function in a loop, at least for reasonably simple calculations like `x**3`.

Also, if you were wondering why your code wasn't compiling, it was because of this line:

```
b[i] = func(a[i]);
```

You were presumably getting the error

> cannot convert ‘SEXP’ to ‘Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type {aka
>   double}’ in assignment

which I resolved by wrapping the return value of `func(a[i])` in `Rcpp::as<double>()` above. However, this clearly isn't worth the trouble because you end up with a much slower function overall anyhow.

Comment: Very good answer. I'm using this for performance sensitive code so I took your advice and removed the call from the Rcpp code and opted for a vectorized solution. Thanks for all the handy tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'transform()' and avoid using loops! Try the following code:

```
List RunFunction(List input, Function f) {

    List output(input.size());

    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(), f);
    output.names() = input.names();
}
```

Comment: You are correct that `std::transform` is a viable alternative to a `for` loop, and generally preferable to loops and iterators in typical C++ code. However, this approach still incurs the same performance overhead that results from making repeated calls to `f` from within the C++. If you run some benchmark tests comparing the `for` loop approach with the `std::transform` approach, you will see that their timings are more or less equal. Also note that the OP's function takes a vector as input rather than a list; although `transform` does work just fine on a list.